# Pandas filter DataFrame with Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Series with the following content.

```
$ import pandas as pd
$ filter = pd.Series(
    data = [True, False, True, True],
    index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    )
$ filter.index.name = 'my_id'

$ print(filter)

my_id
A     True
B    False
C     True
D     True
dtype: bool
```

and a DataFrame like this.

```
$ df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 9, 4],
    'B': [9, 6, 7, 8],
    'C': [10, 91, 32, 13],
    'D': [43, 12, 7, 9],
    'E': [65, 12, 3, 8]
})

$ print(df)

   A  B   C   D   E
0  1  9  10  43  65
1  2  6  91  12  12
2  9  7  32   7   3
3  4  8  13   9   8
```

`filter` has `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` as its indices. `df` has `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` as it column names.

`True` in `filter` means that the corresponding column in `df` will be preserved. `False` in `filter` means that the corresponding column in `df` will be removed. Column `E` in `df` should be removed because `filter` doesn't contain `E`.

How can I generate another DataFrame with column `B`, and `E` removed using `filter`?

I mean I want to create the following DataFrame using `filter` and `df`.

```
   A   C   D
0  1  10  43
1  2  91  12
2  9  32   7
3  4  13   9
```

`df.loc[:, filter]` generates the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1494, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 888, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1869, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1515, in _getbool_axis
    key = check_bool_indexer(labels, key)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2486, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as '
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

`df.loc[:, filter]` works if `df` doesn't contain column `E`.

The real length of the DataFrame (`len(df.columns)`) I encountered in my case contains about 2000 columns. And the length of the Series (`len(filter)`) is about 1999. This makes me difficult to determine which elements are in `df` but not in `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
df.loc[:, filter[filter].index]
```

Explanation: You select the rows in `filter` which contain `True` and take their `index` labels to pick the columns from `df`.

You cannot use the boolean values in `filter` directly because it contains fewer values than there are columns in `df`.

Comment: Thank you. How do you know that `filter[filter].index` works? Is there any official document saying that I can put an `Index` in `loc`?

Comment: Tbh, I just gave it a try and it worked. It don't see it in the official documentation. If you want to be safe you can convert the index into a string list: `df.loc[:, filter[filter].index.values.tolist()]`.